# Use a function defined in a siblings child component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So have a a MainLauyout.vue file

In that file I have a Toolbar component and a content component like so

```
<!--MainLayout.Vue-->
<Toolbar />
<Content></Content>
```

Within Content component I have a search bar with @input

Within the Content component

I have a router-view that displays another vue.

Within that vue, I have a table with a search function defined.

I was wondering how its possible to put that function in the @input that is in the Toolbar component. From what I was able to search they say to use refs but I'm not sure how to get that to work with my layout structure. Can anyone let me know the best way to do this?